What is to be used in place of exfalso omega?
Several examples show that a contradiction in the goal (like "0 > 0 implies something" when trying to use induction on the length of a list) can be handled by
exfalso. omega.

As the Omega module is deprecated the omega tactic is missing. What is the correct way to handle the mentioned situation?
Thank you

Instead of omega, use lia. See https://coq.inria.fr/doc/v8.13/refman/addendum/omega.html

The omega tactic is deprecated in favor of the lia tactic.


Thank you, JoJoModding. lia did resolve the issue.
